# How to test an outdated version of the Firefox web browser on an up to date system?

Tags: debian, firefox, sandbox

I tried to run Firefox 4 on Debian 11 to test a web site for ES5 compatibility.

I managed to run NCSA Mosaic on Debian 11 using Flatpak, but this was too old: it crashes directly, when loading my site.

When I run `flatpak search firefox`, it shows only an up to date version, which I do not need, because Debian has already installed an up to date version.

I know I can run Debian Squeeze in Qemu, but I actually need just on old browser.

Are there any other ways to run really old software?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the binary from their [archive](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)? And 12 years old is ancient for browser software. I doubt that you will be able to load any SSL-enabled site.

Comment: Download, unpack and run: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks! I was not aware of that. And indeed it works. I have not expected this. I thought there will be some library problems.

Comment: @doneal24 I just need the ancient software to test my JavaScript feature detection. I do this without SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download, unpack and run the official binary release: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases

You could also try compiling it but it's a very complicated process and may not necessarily work out for you considering the age of Firefox 4.0.

Comment: This works for Firefox 4. Therefor I have accepted it as an answer. But it fails for many later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [doneal24](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21334/doneal24) and [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) I was able to solve my problem partitially.

I had to create three additional scripts to simplify my workflow.

`get` downloads the required release.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
url=$1
wget -q "$(cat "$url")"
```

`xar` extracts the files into a version directory.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
ar=$1
case $ar in
  firefox-*.tar.bz2)
    version=${ar#firefox-}
    version=${version%.tar.bz2}
    tar xf "$ar" --transform "s!^firefox!${version}!"
    ;;
esac
```

`run` runs the selected version without messing my HOME directory.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
dir=$1
if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
  cd "$dir"
  export HOME=$(pwd)
  ./firefox -no-remote -ProfileManager
fi
```

Example:

```
$ cat > firefox-4.0.1.tar.bz2.url
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/4.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-4.0.1.tar.bz2
$ ./get firefox-4.0.1.tar.bz2.url 
$ ./xar firefox-4.0.1.tar.bz2
$ ./run 4.0.1
```

**Note:**
I was able to run some versions of Firefox, but not all.

My initial assumption, that I might get dependency problems seems to be right. I am not able to run 60.9.0esr on Debian 11 without crashing every tab instantly.

And for all versions after 60 it is necessary to [disable auto-updates](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#disableappupdate) via the `policies.json`

Comment: Please do not use this Firefox version to browse the web, as it contains literally hundreds of vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It is cute that you want to nurse me.

Comment: That wasn't my intent, weird. Some people just know very little about security and take things for granted. I just made sure you knew the truth. You turned it against me and made in an insult.